# Is there a hotel booking website that lets you filter by a highlighted map area?

Tags: online-resources, hotels, accommodation-search-engines

A friend of mine is interested in seeing the [2017 solar eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_eclipse_of_August_21,_2017), however they are having difficulty locating a cheap enough room. The area where the eclipse will be visible is huge, however normal booking websites only let you search by *city*, so it's impossible to select a wide and narrow area.

Is there a hotel booking website where you simply highlight a given area and ask for the cheapest hotels there?

As mentioned by @Carl this [used to be possible](http://lifehacker.com/5825686/google-hotel-finder-lets-you-draw-map-areas-and-filter-hotel-lists-to-find-the-perfect-place-to-stay) on Google Hotel Finder, but that service is no longer available.

Comment: A bit late to be thinking about that now. ["Nearly every hotel and motel room, campground, and in some cases backyards for nearly 100 miles (160 km) miles north and south of the path of totality had been reserved several months if not years in advance."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_eclipse_of_August_21,_2017).

Comment: @GregHewgill surely not *every* room in *every* hotel. There are probably more than several thousands of hotels on the path of the eclipse.

Comment: This article from October 2016 has more anecdotes, plus tips for trying to find a room: [Want to See the 2017 Solar Eclipse? Better Book Your Hotel Room Now](https://www.space.com/34545-book-reservations-for-great-american-eclipse.html)

Comment: And some of us are will simply go outside for the 97 percent view; you're welcome to join me.

Comment: Google *used* to have this http://lifehacker.com/5825686/google-hotel-finder-lets-you-draw-map-areas-and-filter-hotel-lists-to-find-the-perfect-place-to-stay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No booking websites currently support this, however you can at least search a given area for a list of available hotels using Foursquare's [Draw feature](https://foursquare.com/explore?mode=url&polygon=50.10546931761262%2C14.394664764404295%3B50.104616038457635%2C14.39977169036865%3B50.10307459242007%2C14.403676986694336%3B50.10089996812574%2C14.40483570098877%3B50.100046607572295%2C14.404964447021484%3B50.09792690429676%2C14.40487861633301%3B50.09732125756341%2C14.404234886169434%3B50.09633018275811%2C14.401230812072752%3B50.09608241085354%2C14.394793510437012%3B50.0970459610628%2C14.389214515686035%3B50.09886288873478%2C14.385738372802734%3B50.09977132673169%2C14.384665489196777%3B50.10106513292869%2C14.383893013000487%3B50.10271674963851%2C14.383678436279297%3B50.10381779580938%2C14.383978843688963%3B50.10522159297228%2C14.387283325195314%3B50.1055243673587%2C14.392261505126953%3B50.10546931761262%2C14.394664764404295&q=hotel):

[image]

You could then book one of the hotels you've found on a different website.